# Java polymorphism function calls

Tags: java, polymorphism, extends

Having trouble understanding why the output is "3" and "4" for the two function calls. For,

```
g2.foo( t1 );
```

At compile time, g2 is type A, it looks for foo(type C), which it doesn't find in its main class, so it looks at its children class B, then C. So foo(...) should be bind to

```
public void foo(C p) {
    System.out.println("5");
}
```

is subclass C right?

Then during run time g2 will be type C and calls foo(C p) which will result in an output of "5". I am not sure where my logic/understanding of polymorphism is wrong.

```
class A {
    public void foo(A p) {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void foo(B p) {
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public void foo(A p) {
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    public void foo(B p) {
        System.out.println("4");
    }

    public void foo(C p) {
        System.out.println("5");
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A g2 = new C();
        B r2 = new C();
        C t1 = new C();

        g2.foo(t1); // 3

        r2.foo(new C()); // 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At compile time, g2 is type A, it looks for foo(type C), which it doesn't find in its main class, **so it looks at its children class B, then C**. So foo(...) should be bind to ...

This understanding of yours is wrong.

During compile time, since there's not `foo(C)` in type `A`, it marks that the method `foo(A)` will be called (Since `A` is a supertype of `C` and it's the most specific method which matches).

During runtime, `C`'s implementation of the specific method (`foo(A)`) is called and prints `3`. Similar for the next call too.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to remember is that the overloaded method is chosen at compile time based on the compile time type of the instance for which the method is called. The run time type only determines if the chosen method is overridden by an implementation of the run time type.

> g2.foo( t1 )

`g2` has a compile type `A`, which means only `public void foo(A p)` can be chosen at compile time. At run time `g2` in an instance of `C`, which means `public void foo(A p)` of `C` is called, which prints 3.

> r2.foo( new C() )

`r2` has a compile type `B`, so either `public void foo(A p)` or `public void foo(B p)` can be chosen at compile time. `public void foo(B p)` is the best overloaded match (since `B` is more specific than `A`). In run time, `r2` is an instance of `C`, so `public void foo(B p)` of `C` is called, and prints 4.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a function is overridden, the virtual table (v-table) of the derived class has that function mapped with its implementation. So the function call would call the implementation as given by the v-table of that particular class.

In your case, A g2 = new C(); creates the instance of C and hence the v-table would have the foo function mapped with its (C's) implementation.

Now, when the function call happens i.e. on g2.foo(t1), the implementation of the class C will be called as it had it mapped and hence 3 is printed.

Answer (score 0):

When u call g2.foo(t1)
g2 gets the Compile type Object of A which means that that method of A ie

```
 public void foo(A p)
```

but at the runtime g2 is an Object of C Class so public void foo(A p) is called